# Stoping a process then using it again without killing it

Tags: c, process

Is there any way in C programming language , to stop a child process , and then call it again to start from the beginning? I have realised that if I use SIGKILL and then call the child process again nothing happens.

```
void handler {
       printf(“entered handler”);
       kill(getpid(),SIGKILL);
}

int main () {
      pid_t child;
     child=fork();
      if (child<0) printf(“error”);
      else if (child==0) {
             signal(SIGINT,handler);
              pause();
     }
      else { 
           kill(child,SIGINT);
           kill(child,SIGINT);
      }
```

This should print two times “Entered Handler” but it does not. Probably because it cannot call child again . Could I correct this in some way?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If fork-exec into a child process, let it run a bit, `kill(pid, SIGKILL)`, and then fork-exec it again then it should run again from the beginning. You might want to include a bit more detail explaining exactly what you're doing, what you expect, and what actually happens since as it stands, we're just guessing at what's going on.

Comment: SIGSTOP followed by SIGCONT would suspend the process and then let it resume where it was when you stopped it.  But that would not restart it from the beginning.  There is no mechanism in normal C to provide for restarts from the beginning.  All else apart, the process may have had side-effects (changed files, for example), so that even if you restart it somehow, the world it is running in isn't the same as the world that it was first started in.

Comment: I will provide an example code to make it more understandable what I am asking

Comment: A *process* cannot ever genuinely be restarted from the beginning.  You can rerun the same program in a *new* process.  Alternatively, if you have control of the program being run in the child -- as in, you can modify it -- then you may be able to implement means to signal it to behave *as if* it were starting fresh, but there is no mechanism for obtaining such a result for arbitrary programs.

Comment: Other issues with your code notwithstanding, how do you want your terminated process to print anything? To take a grim analogy, if you already killed a person, you do not expect them to scream if you shoot them second time?

Comment: `printf` is not an async-signal-safe function, so you shouldn't call it from a signal handler.

Comment: There is a race between the child setting up its `SIGINT` handler and the parent killing it.

Answer (score 0):

> This should print two times “Entered Handler” but it does not.
>   Probably because it cannot call child again .

There are several problems here, but a general inability to deliver `SIGINT` twice to the same process is not one of them.  The problems include:

- The signal handler delivers a `SIGKILL` to the process in which it is running, effecting that process's immediate termination.  Once terminated, the process will not respond to further signals, so there is no reason to expect that the child would ever print "entered handler" twice.
- There is a race condition between the child installing a handler for `SIGINT` and the parent sending it that signal.  If the child receives the signal before installing a handler for it, then the child will terminate without producing *any* output.
- There is a race condition between the the first signal being accepted by the child and the second being delivered to it.  Normal signals do not queue, so the second will be lost if delivered while the first is still pending.
- There is a race condition between the child blocking in `pause()` and the parent signaling.  If the signal handler were not killing the child, then it would be possible for the child to receive both signals before reaching the `pause()` call, and therefore fail to terminate at all.
- In the event that the child made it to blocking in `pause()` before the parent first signaled it, and if it did not commit suicide by delivering itself a `SIGKILL`, then the signal should cause it to unblock and return from `pause()`, on a path to terminating normally.  Thus, there would then also be a race condition between delivery of the second signal and normal termination of the child.
- The `printf()` function is not async-signal safe.  Calling it from a signal handler produces undefined behavior.
- You should always use `sigaction()` to install signal handlers, not `signal()`, because the behavior of `signal()` is underspecified and varies in practice.  The only safe use for `signal()` is to reset the disposition of a signal to its default.

> Could I correct this in
>   some way?

1. Remove the `kill()` call from the signal handler.
2. Replace the `printf()` call in the signal handler with a corresponding `write()` call.
3. Use `sigaction()` instead of `signal()` to install the handler.  The default flags should be appropriate for your use.
4. Solve the various race conditions by

   1. Having the parent block `SIGINT` (via `sigprocmask()`) before forking, so that it will initially be blocked in the child.
   2. Have the child use `sigsuspend()`, with an appropriate signal mask, instead of `pause()`.
   3. Have the child send some kind of response to the parent after returning from `sigsuspend()` (a signal of its own, perhaps, or a write to a pipe that the parent can read), and have parent await that response before sending the second signal.
   4. Have the child call `sigsuspend()` a second time to receive the second signal.